# Map string in cpp

Tags: c++, string, maps

I want to store all substrings in a unordered_map .I am thinking to use `substr`
function of stl but it worst case time complexity comes out to be O(n) and when I am going to use inside a loop for all indexes of string it will give me O(n^2).

Can we do something better in O(n) by using  pointer or something else so that i can access the substring later.

Comment: try string view. You can represent substring in a very efficient way. However storing *all* substring in a map will be slow no matter what you try. Using the map as a cache for already computer result given a substring will be much much better

Comment: Curious how you plan to use this map, i suspect thats where we should focus on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to copy the sub strings into the map then you can use [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) to store a view of the sub string.  This cost you a pointer and a length, so it's as efficient as it can be.

You can build a vector of all the sub strings like

```
int main()
{
    std::string word = "word";
    auto size = word.size();
    std::vector<std::string_view> parts;
    parts.reserve(size * (size + 1)/2); // reserve space for all the sub strings
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        for(size_t j = i; j < size; ++j)
            parts.emplace_back(word.data() + i, j - i + 1);
}
```